# getting 500 error while implementing signup using google in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-oauth, access-token, http-status-code-500

I am trying to implement signup using google in my project and I am facing issue with receiving token from google. I can redirect to the google page where I need to provide email and password, and then it redirects to the provided "redirect URI". I also receive the code, but I cant receive token. I tried fixing it but unable to figure out why I am receiving this error. the error is generated at

```
$token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);
```

this line of code. and below is the full code.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Google_login extends CI_Controller 
{

public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   
   $this->load->database();
   $this->load->helper('url');
   $this->load->library('session');
}

public function index() 
{
    include_once(APPPATH."libraries/google-app/vendor/autoload.php");
    
    $google_client = new Google_Client();
    
    $google_client->setClientId('Your_Client_Id');
    $google_client->setClientSecret('Secret_Key');
    $google_client->setRedirectUri('Redirect_URI');
    
    $google_client->addScope("email");
    $google_client->addScope("profile");
    
    
    if(!empty($_GET['code']))
    {
        $code = $_GET['code'];
        //echo $code; die();
        $token = array();
        $token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);
    
        if(!isset($token["error"])){
    
            $google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
    
            $google_oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($google_client);
            $google_account_info = $google_oauth->userinfo->get();
           
            $email = $google_account_info->email;
             
             if($email)
             {
             
                  $res = $this->db->query("select * from `user_master` where `email` = '".$email."'");
                  //echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;
                  $record = $res->row();
                  $numrows = $res->num_rows();
        
                  if($numrows!=0)
                  {

                      $this->session->set_userdata('id', $record->id);
                      $this->session->set_userdata('email', $record->email);
                      $this->session->set_userdata('geek', $record->geek_name);
                      $time=date("H:i:s");
                      $this->db->set('login_time',$time);
                      $this->db->set('logout_time',"");
                      $this->db->set('status',"online");
                      $this->db->where('id',$this->session->userdata('id'));
                      $this->db->update('user_master');
                       if($this->session->userdata('id')!="")
                        {
        
                            $query = $this->db->query("select * from `fixergeek_master` where `user_id` = '".$this->session->userdata('id')."'");
                            $numrow = $query->num_rows();
        
                            if($numrow!=0)
                            {
                              redirect('fixer');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              redirect('asker');
                            }
        
                           // redirect('hostaccountoverview');
                        }
           
                  
                  }
                  
                  else
                  {
                    redirect('/', 'refresh');
                  }
                
             }
             
         }
       }  
      else {
    
         redirect($google_client->createAuthUrl());
         //echo "Test Good";
       }
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have faced same issue and i used typecast parameter as array inside count function
in place of
if (count($this->handles) >= $this->maxHandles) in vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/CurlFactory.php you recod this as
if (count((array)$this->handles) >= $this->maxHandles)
error will be solved